# Evaluating results of Naive Bayes Multi Class Prediciton

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I used Naive Bayes in MATLAB (builtin) to predict class label values for my data. My class label can have any value from {1,2,3,4,5}.
I have testLabels as well.
How to measure if testLabels and predictedLabels difference is good?

I tried to use RMSE. but seems like it is giving me value of 1.87124

i DOnt know how to interpret this RMSE value ?

Moreover, are there any standard evaluation methods for doing evaluation of Naive Bayes multi class results?

I know for binary label class I could have used TPR, FPR, Precision , Accuracy etc.

Comment: An RMS error of 1.87 is really high. It means, on average, your label is 1.87 away from what it should be. Assuming the labels {1,...,5} are the input to this RMS function, those results are so off that they're useless.

Comment: If i change my label to binary i.e. {0,1}  ,rmse =0.740   
accuracy= 0.452160493827161, is it very bad too?

Comment: Yes. I mean, if your accuracy is less than 50% that doesn't seem very good, right?

Comment: ya i agree, :( ! thanks so much for helping :) If i change my problem from multi to binary, i have following results : rmse=0.512, accuracy=0.7376, TPR= 0.941, FPR=0.656 , I guess these results are better than previous, but still FPR is not good :S

Comment: What does `{1,2,3,4,5}` mean? In my opinion, you shouldn't be using RMSE as a measure, if the class variable is not continious. You should use classification accuracy.

Comment: You should only use accuracy if you have a balanced dataset, i.e. the number of examples in each class is roughly the same. If not, then use a different metric (such as precision, recall, or F1, which is the harmonic mean of precision and recall).

Answer (score 1):

Multi-class problems can be scored by generalisations of standard metrics: accuracy is obviously applicable to the multi-class case, and recall and precision can be generalised by looking at each class separately. Looking at binary problems is misleading, because a two-way classification task is much easier than a 5 way classification task.

RMSE is not an appropriate metric---consider if you use the labels 1-5 as you did, you get RMSEof 0.74. However, since the labels are arbitrary, you could permute the class labels and get completely different RMSE for *the same decisions*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various metrics. For many cases, accuracy (i.e., how often testLabel is equal predictedLabel) is a good indicator.

You can also look at [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), which measure something akin to Type I and Type II errors.

One thing is certain, though -- it doesn't make any sense to apply RMSE to this case. For example, suppose that you label your data using letters A, B, C, D, E instead of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. This is exactly the same problem (because labels themselves are meaningless), but now RMSE is not computable since it is only applicable to numbers.